# Fragment IllegalStateException after upgrade

Tags: android, android-fragments

Currently, I am using `androidx.fragment:fragment:1.1.0` after upgrading to latest fragment sdk `androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.4` app is crashing. same code is working on 1.1.0 but its crashing on 1.2.4
Crash report

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4696)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:4647)
    at android.app.servertransaction.PauseActivityItem.execute(PauseActivityItem.java:46)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:176)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5235)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:5064)
```

Comment: Can you share your fragment code where the crash is happening?

Comment: its happen when i am adding fragment viva replace

Comment: Share that code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using something like below in your fragment's onCreateView method

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container);
```

Then replace this with this one

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container,false);
```

Comment: its false only.

Comment: Then you can check if view is null or not, before assigning it a value.